# Sorting an array of directory filenames in descending natural order

Tags: php, sorting, filenames, reverse, natsort

I have a content directory to be returned in descending natural order.

I'm using `scandir()` and `natsort()`, but the addition of `array_reverse()` yields no results.

I've been researching using a combination of `opendir()` and `readdir()` as well what ever else to affect this outcome.

The items to be sorted are numbered image files. They are to be returned as: `10` `9` `8` `7` and so on, but like from like `1000` `999` `998` `997` ... until `0`

Here's my current code:

```
$dir = 'dead_dir/dead_content/';
$launcher = scandir($dir);
natsort($launcher);
array_reverse($launcher, false);
foreach ($launcher as $value) {
    if (in_array(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), array('png'))) {
        echo '<img src="dead_dir/dead_content/'.$value.'" />'
    }
}
```

Comment: "but the addition of array_reverse yields no results" --- and why don't you solve this **trivial** issue? Give the example of input array that is transformed to "no results" by `array_reverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $dir='dead_dir/dead_content/';
 $launcher= scandir($dir);
 natsort($launcher);
 $r_launcher = array_reverse($launcher,true);

 foreach($r_launcher as $value ){
   if(in_array(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),array('png'))){
       echo '<img src="dead_dir/dead_content/'.$value.'" />'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple. `array_reverse()` does not modify by reference. You are confusing the behavior of `sort()`ing functions. Instead, you merely need to use the returned value that it generates.  That said, there is a better way.  Read on...

Since PHP5.4, `rsort($array, SORT_NATURAL)` will sort your array in DESC order and treat consecutive numbers as numbers instead of strings.  This is a more direct and concise way technique versus `natsort()`ing then `array_reverse()`ing.

([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AWaOD))
([Demo with `.jpg` extensions](https://3v4l.org/3GOnm))
([Demo with static string before numbers](https://3v4l.org/5G5A4))

I recommend using `glob()` to scan your directory.  This way you can add the `.png` filter in the same call.

```
$dir = 'dead_dir/dead_content/';
$filepaths = glob($dir . '*.png');
rsort($filepaths, SORT_NATURAL);
foreach ($filepaths as $filepath) {
    echo '<img src="' . $filepath . '" />';
}
```

If you would rather omit the path and just return the filenames, just change your **c**urrent **w**orking **d**irectory.

```
chdir('dead_dir/dead_content');
$filenames = glob('*.png');
rsort($filenames, SORT_NATURAL);
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    echo "<div>.png filename => $filename</div>";
}
```

Now, if you require more specialized handling of the filenames, then a custom sorting function may serve you well.

As demonstrated in the following snippet, the spaceship operator will auto-magically type juggle digital strings as integers and give the same result as the `rsort()` solution above.  Using the spaceship operator is still more direct than using `natsort()` then `array_reverse()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iPGhH))

```
$filenames = ["10", "1", "100", "1000", "20", "200", "2"];
usort($filenames, function($a, $b) {
    return $b <=> $a;
});

var_export($filenames);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1000',
  1 => '200',
  2 => '100',
  3 => '20',
  4 => '10',
  5 => '2',
  6 => '1',
)
```

---

If your filenames have leading or trailing non-numeric characters, you can perform the necessary manipulations to strip the unwanted characters while comparing inside of `usort()`.

If anyone is not familiar with how custom sorting works with the spaceship operator...

- To achieve ASC order, write `$a <=> $b`.
- To achieve DESC order, write `$b <=> $a`.

Comment: I'd not heard of the `"spaceship operator"`  before and admittedly it is quite neat when compared to the `ternary` operator but is it available across older versions of PHP?

Comment: It is available since PHP7,  so all non-deprecated versions of PHP can use it.  In other words,  everyone should be using it.

Comment: From PHP7.4, the usort syntax can be even more concise... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59463355/2943403

Answer (score 0):

If your image names will be in the format `123-image_name.jpg`, `2323-image_name.jpg`, ... this will do:

```
/**
 * Compares digits in image names in the format "123-image_name.jpg"
 *
 * @param string $img1 First image name
 * @param string $img2 Second image name
 * @return integer -1 If first image name digit is greater than second one.
 * 0 If image name digits are equal.
 * 1 If first image name digit is smaller than second one.
 */
function compareImageNames($img1, $img2){
    $ptr = '/^(\d+)-/'; // pattern

    // let's get the number out of the image names
    if (preg_match($ptr, $img1, $m1) && preg_match($ptr, $img2, $m2)) {
        $first  = (int) $m1[0]; // first match integer
        $second = (int) $m2[0]; // second match integer

        // equal don't change places
        if($first === $second) return 0;

        // if move first down if it is lower than second
        return ($first < $second) ? 1 : -1;
    } else{
        // image names didn't have a digit in them
        // move them to front
        return 1;
    }
}

// sort array
usort($images, 'compareImageNames');
```