# How to sort an array of numeric strings which also contain numbers. (natural ordering) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, glob

How do you sort an array of strings which also contain numbers.

For example I have used the glob() function to get a list of file names.

By default the array output the files in ascending order but reads each numeric character individually rather than a whole number.

## Default output

```
"C://path/to/file/file.tpl"
"C://path/to/file/file1.tpl"
"C://path/to/file/file11.tpl"
"C://path/to/file/file12.tpl"
....
....
"C://path/to/file/file2.tpl"
```

## Required output

```
"C://path/to/file/file.tpl"
"C://path/to/file/file1.tpl"
"C://path/to/file/file2.tpl"
...
...
"C://path/to/file/file11.tpl"
"C://path/to/file/file12.tpl"
```

Is there a PHP function that performs this?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm aware the question is simple but for those who do not know the term "natural ordering" the answer is not easy to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

> This function implements a sort algorithm that orders alphanumeric strings in the way a human being would while maintaining key/value associations. This is described as a "natural ordering".

Answer (score 6):

`sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);`

or

`natsort($array);`

Natural sorting.