# How do I sort alphabetically with pictures in php?

Tags: php, sorting, arraylist

This is my array thing
Basically right now I have a directory with 100,000 images. All are different names like d2jd29df.png fj329f.png etc. I want it to list them alphabetically on the webpage. Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

[img 1 of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BEfB.png)

[img 2 of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYgFg.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far? post some of your code so we can help

Comment: And please add the code as code, not as a image nobody is going to click :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the entire directory into an array, then sort the array naturally (i.e., the way a human would) alphabetically. Finally, iterate each of the files and echo the filename for each of them.

```
<?php
$files  = array();
$dir    = '/path/to/images';
$handle = opendir($dir);

if ($handle) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
sort($files, SORT_NATURAL);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: To test this I put 4 images in the directory, 1.png,  3.png, 2.png, 4.png.

Doing this, I used your code and it didn't sort the images. Instead it added text to the side. That text is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$dir = "path/to/image";

$images = glob("$dir/*.*");

$items = [];
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $items[] = basename($image);
}
sort($items, SORT_STRING);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item . '<br>';
}
```

Change $dir's value to your directory containing images.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php):

```
$contents = array_diff(scandir('/path/to/my/images/folder'), array('.', '..'));

// If you need to apply a custom sorting algorithm then try using
// natsort(), natcasesort(), usort(), or uasort() on $contents
// before looping through it.
//
// http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

foreach($contents as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

Additionally, you may wish to check out the `sorting_order` parameter of `scandir()`.