# What is the right way to assemble uploaded file chunks in php?

Tags: php

I have a javascript class that splits the file into several chunks:

```
class ChunkFileUploader {
    constructor(options) 
    {
        if ( options.file == null )
        {
            throw new Error('File is required!')
        }
        
        this.endpoint = options.endpoint;
        this.file = options.file;
        this.name = this.uniqueId(20) + '_' + this.uniqueId(10)
        this.extension = this.file.name.split('.').pop()
        this.params = options.params || {}
        this.headers = options.headers || {};
        this.chunkSize = options.chunkSize || 2000000; // 2 mb
        this.maxFileSize = options.maxFileSize;
        this.attempts = options.attempts || 5;
        this.delayBeforeAttempt = options.delayBeforeAttempt || 1;
        this.method = options.method || 'POST';
        this.dynamicChunkSize = options.dynamicChunkSize || false;
        this.maxChunkSize = options.maxChunkSize || 512000;
        this.minChunkSize = options.minChunkSize || 256;
        this.currentChunk = 0;
        // this.totalChunks = Math.ceil(this.file.size / this.chunkSize);
        this.totalChunks = Math.ceil(this.file.size / this.chunkSize);
        this.retryCounts = Array(this.totalChunks).fill(this.attempts);
        this.paused = false;
        this.uploading = false;
        this.events = {};
        this.startTime = 0;
        this.previousTime = 0;
        this.uploadedBytes = 0;

    }
    
    on(eventName, callback) 
    {
        if (!this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName] = [];
        }
        this.events[eventName].push(callback);
    }

    off(eventName, callback) 
    {
        if (this.events[eventName]) {
            const index = this.events[eventName].indexOf(callback);
            if (index !== -1) {
            this.events[eventName].splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    triggerEvent(eventName, detail) 
    {
        if (this.events[eventName]) 
        {
            for (const callback of this.events[eventName]) 
            {
                const event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail });
                callback(event);
            }
        }
    }

    async uploadChunk(chunk) 
    {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('chunk', chunk);
        formData.append('extension', this.extension);
        formData.append('name', this.name);
        formData.append('params', JSON.stringify(this.params) );
        formData.append('chunk_number', this.currentChunk);
        formData.append('total_chunks', this.totalChunks);

        try 
        {
            const now = Date.now();
            const elapsedTime = (now - this.startTime) / 1000; // in seconds
            
            const response = await fetch(this.getUploadUrl(), 
            {
                method: this.method,
                headers: this.getHeaders(),
                body: formData,
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Upload failed');
            }

            this.triggerEvent('chunkSuccess', {
                chunk: this.currentChunk,
                attempts: this.attempts - this.retryCounts[this.currentChunk],
                response,
            });

            this.currentChunk++;
            
            this.uploadedBytes += chunk.size;

            // Calculate progress percentage
            const progress = (this.uploadedBytes / this.file.size) * 100;
            // Calculate transfer speed in KB/s
            const transferSpeed = (this.uploadedBytes / 1024) / elapsedTime;

            // Calculate time left in seconds
            const bytesRemaining = this.file.size - this.uploadedBytes;
            const timeLeft = (bytesRemaining / transferSpeed) || 0;

            // Trigger the 'progress' event with the updated data
            this.triggerEvent('progress', {
                progress,
                timeLeft,
                transferSpeed,
            });

            if (this.currentChunk < this.totalChunks && !this.paused) 
            {
                setTimeout(() => this.uploadNextChunk(), this.delayBeforeAttempt * 1000);
            } 
            else if (this.currentChunk === this.totalChunks) {
                
                this.triggerEvent('success', {
                    response: {
                        json: await response.json(),
                    }
                });
                this.uploading = false;
            }
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            if (this.retryCounts[this.currentChunk] > 0) 
            {
                setTimeout(() => this.uploadChunk(chunk), this.delayBeforeAttempt * 1000);
                this.retryCounts[this.currentChunk]--;
            } 
            else 
            {
                this.triggerEvent('error', 
                {
                    message: 'Max retries reached for chunk',
                    chunkNumber: this.currentChunk,
                    attempts: this.attempts - this.retryCounts[this.currentChunk],
                });
                this.uploading = false;
            }
        }
    }

    uploadNextChunk() 
    {
        if (!this.uploading || this.paused) {
            return;
        }

        const start = this.currentChunk * this.chunkSize;
        const end = Math.min(start + this.chunkSize, this.file.size);
        const chunk = this.file.slice(start, end);
        this.uploadChunk(chunk);
    }

    getUploadUrl() 
    {
        if (typeof this.endpoint === 'function') {
            return this.endpoint(this.file);
        }
        return this.endpoint;
    }

    getHeaders() 
    {
        if (typeof this.headers === 'function') {
            return this.headers(this.file);
        }
        return this.headers;
    }

    uniqueId(length = 10) 
    {
        var result           = '';
        var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
    }

    pause() 
    {
        this.paused = true;
        this.triggerEvent('pause');
    }

    resume() 
    {
        this.paused = false;
        this.triggerEvent('resume');
        if (!this.uploading) {
            this.uploading = true;
            this.uploadNextChunk();
        }
    }

    abort() 
    {
        this.paused = true;
        this.triggerEvent('abort');
    }
}
```

Here's how I handle the uploaded chunks in php:

```
function uploadChunk($src, $args)
{
    $response = [
        'message' => '',
        'error' => '',
        'code' => 404,
        'file' => null
    ];

    $upload_dir = $args['upload_dir'];
    $root_dir = $args['root_dir'];
    $filename = $args['filename'];
    $extension = $args['extension'];
    $chunk_number = $args['chunk_number'];
    $total_chunks = $args['total_chunks'];
    $dynamic_dir = $upload_dir.$filename.'/';
    
    // Create directory if it does not exist
    if (!file_exists($root_dir . $upload_dir)) 
    {
        mkdir($root_dir . $upload_dir, 0777, true);
    }

    // Create directory if it does not exist
    if (!file_exists($root_dir . $dynamic_dir)) 
    {
        mkdir($root_dir . $dynamic_dir, 0777, true);
    }

    // Check if the chunk file already exists
    $chunkFilePath = $root_dir . $dynamic_dir . $filename . '.part' . $chunk_number;
    if (file_exists($chunkFilePath)) 
    {
        $response['message'] = 'Chunk with the same number already exists';
        return json_encode($response);
    }

    if (!move_uploaded_file($src['tmp_name'], $chunkFilePath)) 
    {
        $response['message'] = 'Error occurred while uploading chunk, try again';
        $response['error'] = $src['error'];
        return json_encode($response);
    }

    $response['message'] = 'Chunk successfully uploaded';
    $response['code'] = 200;

    // Check if all chunks have been uploaded
    $uploadedChunks = glob($root_dir . $dynamic_dir . $filename . '.part*');

    if (count($uploadedChunks) == (int)$total_chunks) 
    {
        // All chunks have been uploaded; assemble the original file
        $originalFilePath = $root_dir . $upload_dir . $filename . '.' . $extension;
        $outputStream = fopen($originalFilePath, 'wb');
        foreach ($uploadedChunks as $chunk) 
        {
            $inputStream = fopen($chunk, 'rb');
            stream_copy_to_stream($inputStream, $outputStream);
            fclose($inputStream);
            unlink($chunk);
            rmdir($root_dir . $dynamic_dir);
        }
        fclose($outputStream);

        $fileInfo = [
            'name' => $filename,
            'type' => pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
            'extension' => pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
            'path' => $upload_dir,
            'fullpath' => $upload_dir . $filename,
            'url' => Globals::PROJECT_URL() . $upload_dir . $filename,
        ];

        $response['message'] = 'File successfully assembled from chunks';
        $response['file'] = $fileInfo;
    }

    return json_encode($response);
}
```

**Function usage:**

```
uploadChunk($_FILES['chunk'], [
                'upload_dir' => Globals::FILES_UPLOADS_DIR(),
                'root_dir' => Globals::ROOT_DIR(),
                'filename' => $_POST['name'],
                'extension' => $_POST['extension'], 
                'chunk_number' => $_POST['chunk_number'], 
                'total_chunks' => $_POST['total_chunks'],
            ]);
```

**Problem:**

I successfully upload and assemble files with few chunks (1 to 7 chunks), but I fail with more than 10 chunks, the file is corrupted.

I look anywhere on google and I couldn't find anything related to my problem at all.

Is there any solution to this, I will be grateful.

**Server settings:**

```
upload_max_filesize 7168M
post_max_size 8000M
max_input_vars 200000
max_execution_time 2000
memory_limit=1000M
max_file_uploads=50000
```

**Good File: (10.9MB)**

[image]

**Corrupted file:(30.2MB)**

[image]

Comment: I would suggest not having the chunk upload function try to handle the "All chunks uploaded" detection and separate that into its own `completeUpload()` function to be called by the JS client that checks for the correct number of chunks and then assembles them into the final file. I'm thinking that you may have a race condition between the last N uploads fighting to write/rewrite the final file and/or delete the chunks that another process is trying to use. Aside from that, I would suggest disabling the chunk deletion and verifying that the chunks are correct.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that this happens only when file has more than x amount of chunks, it works smoothly with few chunks like 1 to 7

Comment: And doing it with js is not a solution, as the top reason why chunking the file is because of large file upload support in server side, also I am trying to upload in my localhost, and have the following settings enabled **check my update**

Comment: 1. The problem may be far less _likely_ with 7 or fewer chunks. 2. I didn't say not to chunk, I said not to both send a chunk and trigger check for a complete upload in the same request. Send N chunks and then a client-triggered notification that all chunks have been sent, _then_ assemble the file _once_.

Comment: I tried that, same issue, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Let me guess, chunks are sorted alphabetically and not naturally, so `part1` and `part10` are coming before `part2`? Pad your chunk with `str_pad`, so it would read `part00001` and `part00010` or use `natsort($uploadedChunks)`

Comment: Only checking on existence might be not enough.. if a chunk is present, but not fully written, your resulting file becomes corrupted. You should have a checksum of the content that can be verified on the server side, aka: you'll need some meta data about each chunk to ensure integrity

Comment: Does this answer your questions? [Sorting an array of directory filenames in descending natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7377015/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are blindly taking all files in dir and do not sort them, than it's most likely your chunks are in following *alphabetical* order:

```
abc.part1
abc.part10
abc.part145
abc.part2
abc.part30
```

You need either make them *alphabetically* ordered with `str_pad` when persisting or sort when globing.

1. `str_pad`: `$chunk_number = str_pad($args['chunk_number'], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`
2. `narsort`: `natsort($uploadedChunks);`

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: My question was "What is the right way to assemble uploaded file chunks in php?"
and not "Sorting an array of directory filenames in descending natural order"